# Using PHP mail in a loop forces user to wait until the page displays

Tags: php, email, loops, cron

I have a forum, where users can subscribe to a particular thread. When someone replies to the thread, the reply is added to the DB and an email alert is sent to all the subscribers before the success page is displayed.

FYI - I am not using PHP's mail function, as my hosting provider has a limit of 500 per hour. I am using Google App Engine to send out the emails via curl.

The problem - when the number of subscribers is more than a hundred or so, the user has to wait for way too long before the success page is displayed, because PHP has to loop through each subscriber first. Is there a way to circumvent this without resorting to inserting the emails in the DB and then processing them via a cron?

Hope I've made sense - thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your mail script and force it to run in the background using a shell command.

```
shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/send_notifications.php 'var1' 'var2' >> /path/to/alert_log/paging.log &");
```

Using the `shell_exec` function of PHP, you can tell PHP to run a script in the background. The parameters you see in the `shell_exec` command are seperated by spaces.

- `/path/to/php` - The actual path to PHP on the server (you should be able to just use 'php' here)
- `/path/to/send_notifications.php` - The path to your mail script
- `'var1' 'var2'` - `$_SERVER['argv']` variables you can send to your script will be put in single quotes and spaced after the path to your script.
- `>> /path/to/alert_log/paging.log` - Path to a log file (optional), anything echo'ed in your mail script will be written to this file
- `&` - The **most important** part of this. The `&` tells your server to run this script in the background

Doing it this way, when you execute the mail script, the user submitting the form will not have to wait for the script to finish. The browser will load the page faster and the user can browse away from the confirmation page or even close the browser and the script will continue to run until its completed.

Comment: Good but hosting providers will most likely not allow this type of execution of command line script from php

Comment: Great solution. Make sure though that the script is not placed in a directory which can be reached from the internet or anyone would be able to misuse your mailing functionality.

Comment: This looks promising! Just confirmed that my host supports shell_exec. Going to try it out now - quick question, does this work on Windows? (My development platform is windows, but my website is hosted on Unix)

Comment: @JoostK - will put the script outside the public_html folder, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you using php as fastcgi controlled by php-pfm then you can use the fastcgi_finish_request() function. It's a very powerful function. It will close connection to browser when you call it but will continue to execute the rest of the script.

Ever since I first discovered this function, I've been using it and loving it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the PHP process will not exit before all the API calls to GAE haven been executed. You could however send status updates to the user while the script is executing:

```
// in loop
// sent one message

echo "Sent email to user $email_user \n";
ob_flush();
```

`ob_flush()` will force Apache to send the current buffer to the client. Alternatively you could show the mail page in a separate `<div>` and call the mail script via ajax.

**Edit:** I guess it should be possible send the messages in batches to GAE? What kind of system is sitting at the GAE end (Python/Java)?

Comment: Using Python on GAE - by batches, do you mean sending several emails over a single API call? I don't know if that's possible using GAE, is it?

Comment: I like the Ajax option - I didn't think of that before. But that would also mean that if a user had javascript turned off, the emails would not be sent at all...

Comment: I really would __never__ use Ajax for this kind of job. It then would rely on the client whether or not the emails will be sent, and it's harder to see if the user really posted something (otherwise everyone can make a request to your mailing script, which can then be used for sending dozens of mails)

Comment: @Dickinson - batching means sending several emails to (in this case) GAE. Could you provide a link to the implementation/service you are using on GAE?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should not cron or something but you should use [the task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) to do the processing offline!

> App Engine applications can perform
>   background processing by inserting
>   tasks (modeled as web hooks) into a
>   queue. App Engine will detect the
>   presence of new, ready-to-execute
>   tasks and automatically dispatch them
>   for execution, subject to scheduling
>   criteria.

In the webhook(of the taskqueue) you could make an [asynchronous fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) to your webservice and this way to call will be made asynchronous which ensures your user does not have to wait for it to complete. I hope you understand my solution.

Comment: Just checked this out - the problem is, I'm using PHP to access GAE, which means PHP still needs to add every email to the task queue, which is the slow bit... or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: I believe the taskqueue.add calls are asynchronous so very fast!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more with your implementation. Sending mail, especially in large quantities, is best done with [forking](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/php/process-forking/) or delayed jobs. The idea behind forking is that you enqueue "jobs" and execute them at a later time. The client is not stuck waiting for processes to complete...

One of the more popular projects for PHP is [gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php).

Some other advantages to this approach are:

1. error caching and automatic retries
2. faster serving of pages
3. you can write custom scripts to garbage collect, etc...

Comment: I'm on a shared server :-( - won't be able to install gearman, and a quick search shows that others who have tried forking resulted in the host suspending the script..

Comment: then you're host isn't capable of handling your requests, so you need to move to another hosting provider...

Comment: +1 for switching hosts. Not everythig can be run on a shared server and DV's are pretty cheap these days.

Comment: @prodigitalson - agreed. I'm totally against shared servers. I was once on a shared server without my knowledge and hackers used poorly written code on a sister site to gain sensitive information in my databases

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the email sending into a separate script. One way of doing this would be to create a `mail_queue` table. So inside your loop, you would simply write a row to the database.

Then in another script, you would loop over the set of emails from the database to send out. This script can be run by a cron task, and it can just update that row to 'sent'.

Comment: Yep, a cron did seem like the only solution - will do that if none of the other responses work out, thanks!